# How to verify the setup to see if the user can read and modify the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, console

Here's the homework question:

1. Create 3 users `Jack`, `John`, `Xander`, and create 2 groups: `Family` and `Friend`.
2. Add the user's Jack and John to the Family group, and add Xander to the Friend group. Set up a password for all three users.
3. Log in as Jack, and create a file “Jackfile12”, set up permission to allow John to read and modify the file, but not Xander.
4. Verify your setup to see Jack and John can read and modify the file, but not Xander.

The below code was what I have done until now, anyone can explain how to "verify the setup", which is asked in the question.

```
sudo useradd -m jack
sudo useradd -m john
sudo useradd -m xander
 
sudo groupadd family
sudo groupadd friend

sudo usermod -a -G family jack
sudo usermod -a -G family john
sudo usermod -a -G friend xander

sudo passwd jack
sudo passwd john
sudo passwd xander

su - jack
touch Jackfile12
ls -l Jackfile12

sudo chgrp family Jackfile12
ls -l Jackfile12
chmod g+x Jackfile12

setfacl -m u:Xander:--- Jackfile12
setfacl -m u:Jack:rwx Jackfile12
setfacl -m u:John rwx Jackfile12
sudo -u Xander test -r /home/cisco/Jackfile12; echo "$?"
1
sudo -u Jack test -r /home/cisco/Jackfile12; echo "$?"
0
sudo -u John test -r /home/cisco/Jackfile12; echo "$?"
0
```

Would it be ok if I use the command setfacl to show that the specific user cant access the file? Or do I need to still log in one by one to show?

Comment: "_Would it be ok if I use the command setfacl to show that the specific user cant access the file?_" You need to ask yourself how _setting_ an attribute would confirm whether or not a user could access the file. If you're happy with the answer you've got a route to follow

Answer (score 0):

To "*verify the setup*" you simply need to ensure that the conditions stated in the question are all met, and that as many other variations are not possible.

Statement 4 says, "*Verify your setup to see Jack and John can read and modify the file, but not Xander*".

You need to log in as `jack` and check that this account can read/write the file. Then log in as `john` and check the same. Finally, log in as `xander` and attempt to read and modify the file. (The question isn't quite clear to me whether Xander should be able to read the file but not write it, or have neither read nor write access. You can find this out.)